# How do you force the OAuth Sql Server database objects to be recreated once deleted?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oauth

Using ASP.net 4.5, I created a membership database and set up some open auth providers. In the course of adjusting the database, I deleted the open auth tables (UsersOpenAuthAccounts and UsersOpenAuthData) - I can find no script to generate these items or any other way to regenerate them.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.Net membership libraries create a system table called __MigrationHistory. When these OAuth elements are created, it creates this table (if missing) and creates a record there which acts as a flag indicating that it is not necessary to create the db items. Delete the table, and the membership libraries will recreate the elements.

You will receive an exception indicating that the __MigrationHistory table is missing - ignore this error, as it will be recreated along with the other elements.

BUT BEWARE - __MigrationHistory is a table used by Entity Framework...you may jack it up in try to fix this, so keep a backup handy.